# Há algum componente que substitua o SpinEdit do Windows Forms no WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Dou preferência por componentes de código aberto, ou se possível uma forma de adaptação, pois não encontrei nenhum SpinEdit ou similar no WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instale o pacote via `nuget` [Extended.Wpf.Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/) que o mesmo oferece um componente `SingleUpDown`. Depois que foi instalado configure da seguinte forma:

Adicione a configuração:

> `xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"`

no código:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <wpfTool:SingleUpDown Value="1564" Margin="39,70,311,223"
                              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <wpfTool:SingleUpDown.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0.309"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </wpfTool:SingleUpDown.RenderTransform>
        </wpfTool:SingleUpDown>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns componentes no ***Extended WPF Toolkit*** que vão te ajudar.

[DecimalUpDown](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DecimalUpDown)
O controle DecimalUpDown fornece um TextBox com botões que permitem aumentar e diminuir valores `Nullable <Decimal>`

[DoubleUpDown](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DoubleUpDown)
O controle DoubleUpDown fornece um TextBox com botões que permitem aumentar e diminuir valores `Nullable <Double>`

[IntegerUpDown](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/IntegerUpDown)
O controle IntegerUpDown fornece um TextBox com botões que permitem aumentar e diminuir valores `Nullable <int>`

Acesse o link pelos nomes dos componentes, ou então acesse [aqui](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) o Toolkit